# Equation using Rolles theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a real valued twice differentiable function on interval $[1,5]$ such that $f(1) = f(5) = 0$ and $f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)$, $ x\in[1,5] $, then $(f(2) + f(4) – f'(3))$ is equal to____

I tried to approach the question using the following concept

Twice differentiable means the double derivative of the function.

If a function is twice differentiable, then the second derivative of the function exists.

From twice differentiable of a function we get the maxima and minima of the function.

If $f''(x)<0$  at $x=a$, then function is maxima at $x=a$.

If $f''(x)>0$  at $x=a$, then function is maxima at $x=a$.

If we apply Rolles theorem then $f(1)=f(5)=0$ but how do we use the following in solving the problem

$f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)$ it is possible when function if of the type $e^x$ but this is an increasing function hence how we will approach this problem.

Comment: The solution will be of the type $f(x) = c_1e^{a_1x}+c_2e^{a_2x}$, which can have a max or min.

Answer (score 4):

The function $f$ is the solution of a linear second-order differential equation. Since $f(1)=f(5)=0$, uniqueness of solution implies that $f \equiv 0$. So, the answer must be zero.

---

The solution of $f''(x)+f'(x)-f(x)$ can be obtained from the roots of $D^2+D-1$ because, if we test solutions of the form $e^{Dx}$, we arrive at

$$
(e^{Dx})'' + (e^{Dx})'-e^{Dx}=0 \Leftrightarrow (D^2+D-1) e^{Dx} = 0
$$

So, we can see that any solution will be of the form
$$
f(x)= c_1
   e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) x}+c_2
   e^{\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)
   x},
$$

where the constants $c_1, c_2$ can be computed from the conditions $f(1)=f(5)=0$. This leads to $c_1=c_2=0$, hence $f(x)\equiv 0$.